# sSearch: Filter Records does not start filtering with first letters but containing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've datatables.js and the .dataTable method with "sSearch": "Filter records" what is wrong when I type first letters it finds all records that contain those letters instead of only those that starts with this letters. How could I customize this method to start the filtering by the first letter when I type "DO" it will find all records that starts with "DO" in any column.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter records:"
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Hi, could you add the code of the problem please?

Comment: Hi @Sdf19, can you also add the relevant HTML?